# Implement a Clock in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime

How idiomatic is my code?

```
var Clock = function(hour, minute) {
  this.hour = hour || 0;
  this.minute = minute || 0;

  this.plus = function(minutes) {
    computed_minutes = this.minute + minutes
    if (computed_minutes > 60) {
      this.minute = computed_minutes % 60
      this.hour += computed_minutes / 60
    } else {
      this.minute = computed_minutes
    }
    if (this.hour >= 24) {
      this.hour = this.hour - 24
    }
    this.hour = Math.round(this.hour)
    this.minute = Math.round(this.minute)
    return this;
  },

  this.minus = function(minutes) {
    computed_minutes = this.minute - minutes
    if (computed_minutes < 0) {
      this.minute = 60 + computed_minutes % 60
      this.hour -= (1 + Math.abs(computed_minutes / 60))
    } else {
      this.minute = computed_minutes;
    }
    if (this.hour < 0) {
      this.hour = 24 + this.hour
    }

    this.hour = Math.round(this.hour)
    this.minute = Math.round(this.minute)

    return this;
  },

  this.equals = function(other) {
    return this.hour == other.hour && this.minute == other.minute;
  }

}

Clock.at = function(hour, minute) {
  c = new Clock(hour, minute);
  return c;
}

Clock.prototype.toString = function() {
  function format(n) {
    return n >= 10 ? n : "0" + n;
  }
  return format(this.hour) + ":" + format(this.minute)
}

module.exports = Clock;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some issues:

- Every instance of `Clock` gets its own instance of `plus` and `minus` rather than attaching these functions to the prototype.
- `Clock.at` sets a global variable `c`.
- `Clock.prototype.toString` creates the `format` function each time it is called; you can move this out of the function and into a different scope so it is only created once.
- `plus` and `minus` do a lot of checking that could be moved into a single `set` function and then this can also be called from the constructor (so that the same checks and rounding is also done in the constructor).
- `24` and `60` appear as magic constants. In this context it is easy to understand what they are but it would be better to assign them to named constants (`HOURS_PER_DAY` and `MINUTES_PER_HOUR`) that identify why those magic numbers are being used.

My suggestions:

```
module.export = (function(){
    var Clock = function( hours, minutes ) {
      this.set( hours, minutes )
    }

    Clock.at = function(hours, minutes) {
      return new Clock(hours, minutes);
    }

    Clock.HOURS_PER_DAY = 24;
    Clock.MINUTES_PER_HOUR = 60;

    Clock.prototype.set = function( hours, minutes ){
        var hrs = Math.round( hours || 0 ); 
        var mns = Math.round( minutes || 0 );

        this.hour = ( hrs + Math.floor( mns / Clock.MINUTES_PER_HOUR ) ) % Clock.HOURS_PER_DAY;
        if ( this.hour < 0 )
        {
            this.hour += Clock.HOURS_PER_DAY;
        }

        this.minute = mns % Clock.MINUTES_PER_HOUR;
        if ( this.minute < 0 )
        {
            this.minute += Clock.MINUTES_PER_HOUR;
        }

        return this;
    }

    Clock.prototype.plus = function(minutes) {
     return this.set( this.hour, this.minute + minutes )
    },

    Clock.prototype.minus = function(minutes) {
     return this.set( this.hour, this.minute - minutes );
    },

    Clock.prototype.equals = function(other) {
     return this.hour == other.hour && this.minute == other.minute;
    }

    function format(n) {
        return n >= 10 ? n : "0" + n;
    }

    Clock.prototype.toString = function() {
          return format(this.hour) + ":" + format(this.minute)
    }

    return Clock;
})();
```

Comment: Some of this code seems worse than the original. Why introduce the variables `hrs` and `mns`?

Comment: To be sure, your review itself is solid

Comment: `mns` is used twice so is worth introducing a variable to make the code more efficient. They are also introduced so it is easier to review the code and see at a glance how the input is modified (i.e. `0` if `undefined` and rounded to the nearest integer); otherwise it would be buried in the middle of a long line of code.

Comment: The `format` function could be written better as `function format(n) { return ('0' + n).slice(-2); }`

Comment: @Ben http://jsperf.com/format-number-to-2-character-stringg - The example by the OP (and that I've used) is several orders of magnitude faster than slicing the string and is also more idiomatic.

Comment: ^ Good point. Didn't think to benchmark that before posting. Cheers. :-)

Answer (score 2):

From an idiomatic perspective;

- As MT0 mentioned, you should use more `prototype`
- Use lowerCamelCase, so `computed_minutes` -> `computedMinutes`
- In the JavaScript Date API you only have 1 `addMinutes` and then you can call it with positive or negative numbers to add or remove minutes. From an idiomatic perspective, you could considering doing the same. You would also be reducing some duplicated code

Other than your code is quite idiomatic.

Comment: +1 for suggesting mimicking Date object functionality. I really enjoy adding negative time to objects, it's so much simpler!